# Package Angular 6 library without dependencies

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-packagr

I have an Angular 6 library which contains couple of modules with its routes. This library also works as a standalone application.

I have used ng-packagr to pack and publish the library. When packing all the dependencies included in package.json dependencies also gets shipped and is installed when consumed by an application.

This behaviour results in duplication of angular core libraries and app does not start.

One of ways i have handled is include all the dependencies as devDependencies in package.json, so they wont get shipped. Is there any better way to handle this without moving to dev dependencies ?

Comment: set them up as "peerDependencies"?

Comment: Though when running as an application , peerDependencies are not installed and need to be setup manually. Can this be done automatically ?

Comment: the app only needs to install the dependency, all other projects/libs would require them as a peer dependency

Comment: My App already has all @angular deps, if i include them as deps and as peerDeps then they gets installed too which results in duplication.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like having dependencies as devDependencies is the solution for now, as having just peer dependencies works when inported as a library but it doesn't install deps when using in an application.